# Split and replace string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a string in a format:

```
string path="/fm/Templates/testTemplate/css/article.jpg";
```

I want to split this with second '/' and replace with '/' to '\\' want a result like this.

```
string newPath="\\Templates\\testTemplate\\css\\article.jpg";
```

My `path` is dynamic created so folder hierarchy is not fixed. 
What is the best way to do this.May I split first `string path` with `/` and go to loop to re-concate this and repalce with  '/' to '\\' or there any easy way I am missing.

Comment: `string.Replace("/", "\\");`?

Comment: Sounds like you are introducing some security hole, if you process paths from the public web. I would try "/fm/../../Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts" if I would be some intruder...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string path = "/fm/Templates/testTemplate/css/article.jpg";
path = path.Substring(path.IndexOf('/', 1)).Replace("/", "\\\\");
```

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just use [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx)?

Comment: I want to rid off '/fm/' first and then replace ?

Comment: I think you are just thinking too much for a simple problem. Just remove /fm/ first then followed by replacing the rest of the '/'

Comment: newPath = path.Replace("/", "\\");

Comment: its dyanamic so instead of `/fm/` there may be `/am/`this is a  real problem?

Comment: if the number of characters are going to be same i.e 2 (am, fm) then just remove 4 characters at the begining which includes the / too.

Comment: @ShreeKhanal `path = Regex.Repalce("^/[^/]*/", "", path); path = path.Replace("/", "\\");`. Just do it in pieces.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
public static int nthOccurrence(String str, char c, int n)
{
    int pos = str.IndexOf(c, 0);
    while (n-- > 0 && pos != -1)
        pos = str.IndexOf(c, pos + 1);
    return pos;
}    

string path = "/fm/Templates/testTemplate/css/article.jpg";

int index = nthOccurrence(path, '/', 1);
string newpath = path.Substring(index).Replace("/", "\\");
```

**OUTPUT:** `"\\Templates\\testTemplate\\css\\article.jpg"`

Comment: `/fm/` is still there i want to rid off from it ?

Comment: Updated my answer..now it may help you..@ShreeKhanal

Answer (score 0):

You may create a new string after removing the first item from the path. The following will give you the desired result. It may be optimized.

You can try:

- Split the string on char `/` and remove empty entries.
- Get a new array after disregarding the first item from the split array
- Use `string.Join` to create the new string with `\\` as separator.

Here is the code:

```
string path = "/fm/Templates/testTemplate/css/article.jpg";
string[] temp = path.Split("/".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var newTemp = temp.AsEnumerable().Where((r, index) => index > 0);
string newPath2 = string.Join("\\", newTemp);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with individual segments of your path (and not just replacing the direction of the slashes), the System.Uri class will help (.Segments property).

Eg from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.segments.aspx)

```
Uri uriAddress1 = new Uri("http://www.contoso.com/title/index.htm");
Console.WriteLine("The parts are {0}, {1}, {2}", uriAddress1.Segments[0], uriAddress1.Segments[1], uriAddress1.Segments[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code.

```
string path="/fm/Templates/testTemplate/css/article.jpg"; 
string newpath = path.Replace("/fm", string.Empty).Replace("/","\\");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
string path = "/fm/Templates/testTemplate/css/article.jpg";
string[] oPath = path.Split('/');
string newPath = @"\\" + string.Join(@"\\", oPath, 2, oPath.Length - 2);
Console.WriteLine(newPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your string manipulation really so time critical that you need to do everything at once? It's much easier just to break it down into parts:

```
// First remove the leading /../ section:
path = Regex.Replace("^/[^/]*/", "", path);

// Then replace any remaining /s with \s:
path = path.Replace("/", "\\");
```